# How to sort ArrayList<Object> in Ascending order android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have a requirement to sort `ArrayList<Object>`(Custom objects) in Ascending order based upon name. For that purpose I am using comparator method as like

**My ArrayList :**

`ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();`

**Code I am using:**

```
   Comparator<Model> comparator = new Comparator<Model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(CarsModel lhs, CarsModel rhs) {

                String  left = lhs.getName();
                String right = rhs.getName();

                return left.compareTo(right);

            }
        };

   ArrayList<Model> sortedModel = Collections.sort(modelList,comparator);

//While I try to fetch the sorted ArrayList, I am getting error message
```

I am completely stuck up and really dont know how to proceed further in order to get sorted list of `ArrayList<Object>`. Please help me with this. Any help and solutions would be helpful for me.  I am posting my exact scenario for your reference. Thanks in advance.

**Example:**

```
ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
modelList.add(new Model("chandru"));
modelList.add(new Model("mani"));
modelList.add(new Model("vivek"));
modelList.add(new Model("david"));
```

**Normal List:**

```
for(Model mod : modelList){
  Log.i("names", mod.getName());
}
```

**Output :**

```
chandru
mani
vivek
david
```

**My requirement after sorting to be like:**

```
for(Model mod : modelList){
  Log.i("names", mod.getName());
}
```

**Output :**

```
chandru
david
mani
vivek
```

Comment: The output seems the same as the output in the requirement. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What's not working?

Comment: I need to assign the sorted array in ArrayList<Model>

Comment: Can you explain the error. What is the output of your code?

Comment: I am getting Incompatible type error.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your approach was right. Make your `Comparator` inner like in the following example (or you can create a new class instead):

```
ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
modelList.add(new Model("chandru"));
modelList.add(new Model("mani"));
modelList.add(new Model("vivek"));
modelList.add(new Model("david"));

Collections.sort(modelList, new Comparator<Model>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
        return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
    }
});
```

*output*:

```
chandru
david
mani
vivek
```

Comment: can you tell for descending order

Comment: @Prasad Change `lhs` and `rhs` positions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it works well and saved much of my time!

Answer (score 7):

```
 Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Actors>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Actors lhs, Actors rhs) {
       return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
     }
    });
```

Comment: this code is work properly i will use this code....this code work in string & also integer value

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(modelList, (lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName()));
```