# Custom dropdown/popup with shorting ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android

i'll create a custom Dropdown/popup and it's work perfect.

See below Custom dropdown/popup code:

```
case R.id.linerSort:
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, linerSort);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater()
                        .inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity,
                                "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();
                break;
```

- Now i want to sorting a list which i select a item of Dropdown/popup.
- Sorting is according to `ArrayList<Object>` So how to do that with my code.
- if suppose i select a price then is shorting a acceding or descending order.

i follow this link: [How to sort ArrayList<Object> in Ascending order android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160742/how-to-sort-arraylistobject-in-ascending-order-android) But how to i merge with my code i don't understand.

Comment: could you please be more specific on what has to be sorted? the `menuItem` based on the `ArrayList<Object>` or what?

Comment: if suppose i select a price then is shorting a acceding or descending order.  @Lino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to sort in ascending or descending order:

```
case R.id.HighToLow:
          Collections.sort(subCategoryViewDataBeanArrayList, new Comparator<SubCategoryViewDataBean>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(SubCategoryViewDataBean s1, SubCategoryViewDataBean s2) {
          return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s2.price)) - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s1.price));
          }
        });
        BindData(subCategoryViewDataBeanArrayList);
        break;

        case R.id.LowToHigh:
                    Collections.sort(subCategoryViewDataBeanArrayList, new Comparator<SubCategoryViewDataBean>() {
                     @Override
                     public int compare(SubCategoryViewDataBean s1, SubCategoryViewDataBean s2) {
                     return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s1.price)) - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s2.price));

                     }
                  });
                  BindData(subCategoryViewDataBeanArrayList);
```